# What can we do with an exe program?

Tags: java, apk, exe

Is .exe the "final form" of a program that we cant even get a single code out of it? Is it impossible to convert it into any other file type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> EXE is a file extension for an executable file format. An executable is a file that contains a program - that is, a particular kind of file that is capable of being executed or run as a program in the computer. An executable file can be run by a program in Microsoft DOS or Windows through a command or a double click.

Essentially it is one of the many possible "final forms" of a program. You can convert exes into different file types like .msi. It is possible to get code out of a exe file using a special program but normally it is distorted as the code has to be decompiled.

Comment: thank you very much, Ryan, for the fast reply! I really appreciated ur help :)

Comment: is it possible to convert the exe into an app?

Comment: a app? as in mobile app?

Comment: i did upvote ur answer but the number is not increasing :/

Comment: i think its becaz i do not have a reputation of 15 or more... thats why its not upvoting :/

Comment: i editted my answer for your interest in converting exe

Comment: oh btw, i did checked the link u sent to me, and it didnt work. The links to download the converters are most likely "scam surveys" which wants u to place ur mobile phone number into it.

Comment: link removed i apologize it looked appealing to me at first.

Comment: it's ok...so does that means there's no way of converting it then?

Comment: im sorry if i did not reply ur comment asap, it might mean that im offline at that time since it has actually pass midnigth here. XD